# Key binding to go up by one directory (in Bash)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, key-bindings

In Zsh, I have a key binding to go up by one directory (very useful):

```
# C-M-u: up-directory
up-directory() {
    builtin cd .. && zle reset-prompt
}
zle -N up-directory
bindkey '\e\C-u' up-directory
```

It's very nice. So nice that I would like to get it as well in my Bash config.

How can we do that?

Comment: @oguzismail Thanks for the tip. Is it the same for Zsh?  Is there some guideline to find the right bucket for asking a question?

Comment: Not that I know of. I don't follow [tag:zsh] tag, check if there are questions like this there.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do that. 
It's not as elegant or straight forward as with zsh but it's doable in bash using `bind`.
You can not only bind built in Readline functions (listed with `bind -l`) but other macros and shell functions too.

`bind -m emacs -x '"\C-i":"cd .."'` will bind a shell command (`cd ..`) to the keys (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>) in emacs mode (the default mode). (Ctrl+i is unbound by default, u isn't)

Note that your prompt will probably not reflect the change. 
If you leave out `-x` the string will instead be typed out for you so `"cd ..\n"` achieves the same result.

*Edit*: `bind` is how you bind keys and macros can accomplish what you want even though no built in thing exists.

If you end your PS1 prompt with `\033[K` (erase to eol) and can use 
`bind -m emacs '"\C-i":" cd ..&&echo -e \"\\033[2A\"\n"'` to do what you want.
This will first print `cd ..` then control chars to move the cursor up and run it (with `\n`). 
The end of your PS1 prevents it from showing. This *is* a hack but it shows that it's doable.

Comment: Your code just beeps on my system. Nothing happens?  However, indeed, if I leave out the `-x`, then it just writes `cd ..` (in fact without the newline - which means that multiple `C-u` lead to `cd.. cd.. cd..` being printed).

Comment: Of course, the goal is that the PATH written in the prompt gets updated along the way, otherwise we'd not know where we are when executing commands.

Comment: Make sure the key sequence is unused. `\C-u` is `unix-line-discard` usually.

Comment: indeed the `cd` works, when this is bound to a free key binding. However, as the prompt is not refreshed, that's not really usable...

Comment: zsh has that feature, bash doesn't best you can hope for is a kludge. Updated by solution with an example of that.

Comment: I do have a multiline prompt, so this is not working so well. Could certainly be adapted, but I then prefer this intermediate solution, which is not a hack: `bind '"\e\C-u": "cd ..\n"'`

Answer (score 2):

In case someone still need this:

This binds `cd ..` to F2. Keeps the currently typed command and throws an updated prompt.

```bash
bind '"\eOQ": "\C-a\C-kcd ..\C-m\C-y"'
```

How it works:

- `\eOQ` is `F2` on my terminal
- `C-a` beginning-of-line
- `C-k` kill-line
- `cd ..`
- `C-m` accept-line
- `C-y` yank <- this restores the killed line

However the `cd ..` command appears in the screen. If it bothers you, use this instead:

```bash
bind -x '"\201":cd ..'
bind '"\eOQ": "\C-a\C-k\201\C-m\C-y"'
```

`\201` is non existent key, an empty slot we can use.

Note 1: It doesn't save the cursor position, after `F2` the cursor lands on the end of the line, which is a little limitation.

Note 2: The original was: `bind '"\eOQ": " \C-a\C-k\201\C-m\C-y\C-b\C-d"'` which adds an extra space, then removes it. I don't know why, maybe it was some workaround in the old ages when i wrote this, but it looks it does not needed now.

Comment: Awesome! Even if it's a bit hacky, this is the only working solution I found after a few tries since several years. Thank you for the "non existent key" trick, in my case it's very useful because the command is not `cd ..` but an obscure internal function like `__atuin_cd`